# execute command inside cmd application with one command

Tags: batch-file, join, cmd, command

I installed Linphone application
http://www.linphone.org/technical-corner/linphone/documentation

I am running this application via cmd executing this command

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Linphone\bin\linphonec.exe"
```

then I make the call through this command

```
call number@x.x.x.x
```

I want to join the tow commands in one line so the cmd start the linphone then execute the call command inside the linphone

Output with & operator

```
C:\Users\Desktop\1>CD "C:\Program Files (x86)\Linphone\bin\"

C:\Program Files (x86)\Linphone\bin>linphonec.exe   & call number@x.x.x.x
WARNING: no real random source present!
Ready
Warning: video is disabled in linphonec, use -V or -C or -D to enable.
linphonec>
```

how i can do that in cmd ?

Answer (score 1):

```
CD C:\Program Files (x86)\Linphone\bin\
echo call number@x.x.x.x|linphonec.exe
```

may work.

Comment: I used your code alone it was perfect but when i entered it in a loop in my bat file like this `FOR /F "tokens=*" %%K IN ('echo call %%H%%Z@%%G|"C:\Program Files (x86)\Linphone\bin\linphonec.exe"')` I got this error ` | was unexpected at this time ` what is this ?

Comment: Just the way batch syntax works - the cure is to insert a caret `^` before the pipe `|` so that batch knows that the pipe is part of the command to be executed. `call %%H%%Z@%%G^|"C:\Progra...` should work for you.